# Hibernate and @ElementCollection: Duplicate Key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a cronjob running, calculating a lot of stuff once a day.

There are 2 entites involved.

First one is the "KPI" Entity, containing information about user activities. 
Every KPI entity is 1:1 related to a user ofc. the KPI entity itself is related 1:n to a more detailed drill down. (It's a element collection inside the KPI entity).

Simpliefied:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DBConstants.KPI_TABLE_NAME)
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "kpi.byUser", query = "SELECT k FROM KPIEntity k WHERE k.user = :user"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "kpi.all", query = "SELECT k FROM KPIEntity k"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "kpi.allactiveusers", query = "SELECT k FROM KPIEntity k WHERE k.user.accountActive = :accountstatus") })
public class KPIEntity implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;

   @Column
   private long tasksCompleted;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = java.lang.Long.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyClass(java.lang.String.class)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "taskKey")
    @CollectionTable(name = "KPItaskDrilldown", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    @Column(name = "count")
    private Map<String, Long> tasksCompletedPerType;
}
```

So, i assume that hibernate creates 2 tables:

"KPIs":

```
id | tasksCompleted
1  | 250
2  | 50
```

KPItaskDrilldown

```
kpi_id | tasksCompletedPerType | count
1      | A                     | 20
1      | B                     | 75
...
```

This "works" - for the first run. But if the cronjob runs again, i receive Duplicate-Key-MySQL-Errors.

I noticed, that Hibernate has created a composite Key on the drilldown table: `kpi_id, tasksCompletedPerType`. This seems fine so far.

But even if i do an UPDATE on the KPI entity, Hibernate seems to try to INSERT the values into the second table - which will fail due to the constraint.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which database server are you using? AFAIK, oracle does not support 'GenerationType.IDENTITY'. Also, can you paste the code you are using to save the entity?

Comment: We are having the same problem. Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @BahadırYağan Not yet - i'm giving up on this now :P